# Responsive Android App Design

Tags: java, android, responsive-design

My android app is almost done!
But now, I need to have a responsive design.
I've read the android developers pages about that, but on my samsung note 2 the responsive design doesn't work...
I've got 4 folders for the layout: small, normal, large, xlarge. 
Also I've got the tags in the manifest which are described at the developers page.
Is this maybe only by the samsung note 2 or by every device?

Hope you can help! 
Thanks!

Comment: you need to be more specific than just "doesn't work". Seems you've got a lot to learn, but one tip I'll give is that you should be using smallest width (ex `/layout-sw600dp`) as the configuration qualifiers for your folders, not small/normal/large/xlarge.

Answer (score 0):

To design responsive application is some what difficult. Please follow the below instructions.

- Don't specify width and height in dps in layout.
- Design your layout by using weights.
- Maintain icons in different folder.
- Finally design each layout carefully with check in all screens.

Please find the sample link for your reference.

[Responsive Android app design](http://www.objc.io/issue-11/responsive-android-applications.html)

Hope this  will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used **Fragment** to make your app responsive to all type of device? As my experience, for big screen devices like Note 2 or Tab you have to use fragment and  you have to make an extra layout for those devices. In case of me same problem happened and only padding margin responsiveness doesn't work all time at reality though they show on emulators.

You can know about using Fragment to make applications responsive for all devices from here:
[Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)